# Unsure about the proper use of Lorentz transform

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

I'm not very comfortable with handling Lorentz transformations and I often have doubts...

Consider for example the following situation, illustrated by the diagram below:
[image]
A rod of length $L$ is placed in the frame of reference $R$ (the rest frame) and 2 synchronized clocks (indicating the same time) are attached to the 2 ends of the rod: an observer in $R$ can read the same time $t$ indicated on the 2 clocks.

The moving frame $R’$ is moving uniformly at velocity $v$ relative to $R$, along the $x-axis$. The goal is to know what an observer in $R’$ (therefore moving with $R’$) will read on the 2 clocks?

I make the following reasoning: the ends of the rod can be associated with 2 space-time coordinate events:

$\begin{pmatrix}t_1=t \\ x_1=0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}t_2=t \\ x_2=L \end{pmatrix}$ in $R$ ;  $\begin{pmatrix}t'_1 \\ x'_1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}t'_2 \\ x'_2 \end{pmatrix}$ in $R’$.

The Lorentz transformation associated with the problem should be written (if I am not mistaken...):

$$\begin{cases} 
t'_2 - t'_1 = \Delta t’ = \gamma(\Delta t - \frac{v \Delta x}{c^2}) \\
x'_2 - x'_1 = \Delta x’ = \gamma(\Delta x – v \Delta t)
\end{cases}$$

Given that $\Delta t = 0$ and that $\Delta x = L$, we simply have:

$$\begin{cases} 
\Delta t’ = - \frac{\gamma v L}{c^2} \\
\Delta x’ = \gamma L
\end{cases}$$

What surprises me in this reasoning is that the length of the rod, observed by the observer moving with $R'$, is greater than the length observed by the observer at rest in $R$...

I am therefore addressing people more gifted than me to ask them: what would you deduce from the situation explained by the diagram?

Comment: Given a set of $\{(t_1,x_1),(t_2,x_2)\}$ and a Lorentz transformation, you can find all the $(t^\prime,x^\prime)$ those events in spacetime will be newly transformed to. What you will find is that, indeed, the new $x_2^\prime-x_1^\prime>L$, but that is not an issue, because $t_2^\prime-t_1^\prime\neq0$, and nobody in that frame would want to measure distances of things that are moving in their frame, using different times. You should find a proper textbook of SR to properly learn from.

Comment: The measurements of the ends of the rod in $\mathcal{R'}$ must be made simultaneously, i.e. $t'_{1}=t'_{2}$, and the simple way to do it is to take the inverse transformation $\Delta x=\gamma(\Delta x'+v\Delta t')=\gamma \Delta x'$...

Comment: Thanks, @The Tiler, `must be made simultaneously` makes sense. Now, using the inverse transform leads to:
$\Delta x = \gamma \Delta x'$ and $\Delta t = v \gamma \Delta x' / c^2$, right?
So that $\Delta t = v \Delta x / c^2 = v L / c^2$, right?
What conclusion could I draw from this? That the 2 clocks, if controlled in $R$, are not synchronized? Such situation looks to me very strange...
Or, as @naturallyInconsistent said, the problem comes simply from the fact that I don't know how to formulate the question properly?...

Comment: I think this link will clear things up a bit. 
 
 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/731491/how-to-derive-the-vx-c2-term-from-first-principles/731628#comment1636491_731628     ( My English is terrible :-}   )

Comment: (don't worry; as a French, so is mine...)
I will give a careful look to the link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Lengths are measured by as the spatial separation of two events **at the same time**. But the notion of "same time" depends on the frame. If the length of an object (assumed to be stationary in $S$) is measured in frame $S$, the two measurements occur at the same time ($\Delta t = 0$) in $S$. But in $S'$, moving at velocity $v$ relative to $S$, they do not. As you have found out, they are a time $\Delta t' = -\gamma v L/c^2$ apart. This is known as the "rear clock ahead" effect, which is better known as loss of simultaneity. The negative sign of $\Delta t'$ tells us that the event (measurement) at the rear end occurs first, which is why the length seems longer than it should be (remember that the object is moving in this frame, so measurements not at the same time do not give the length). Thus, in order to obtain the actual length as measured in $S'$, we need to compensate by $v\Delta t'$ so it becomes $$L' = \gamma L - \gamma\frac{Lv^2}{c^2} = \gamma L\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right) = \frac{L}{\gamma}$$ which is the standard result of length contraction.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but in `Don Koks`in `(2006). Special Relativity and the Lorentz Transform. In: Explorations in Mathematical Physics. Springer, New York, NY. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-32793-8_5` (**page 191**) his calculation leads to $\Delta t' = - \frac{v L}{c^2}) $, and there is no $\gamma$ factor...

Comment: @Andrew That is incorrect. There must be a factor of $\gamma$. Are you sure that they are using the same definition of $L$?

Comment: Hi @Vincent, actually I don't know. I read the corresponding pages, but I am lost about who is measuring what in what frame, as there is no picture describing how the measurement are made. At least, things seem to be totally clear for the author. It means that I am not able to understand which kind of situation he describes... So, trying to apply a Lorentz transform to a situation I don't understand lead me obviously to errors, (which I even don't understand how to correct...)

Comment: @Andrew The point is that if you measure the length of an object to be $L$ in a frame in which it is stationary (by taking the two ends simultaneously), then the time difference between the same two measurements in a frame moving with relative velocity $v$ will be $\gamma vL/c^2$, which is what I said originally. Obviously, in the latter frame, the object will have a length of $L/\gamma$ due to length contraction. The only way your book could be correct is if it defined $L$ to be the length in the moving frame rather than the stationary frame.

Comment: (1) I reread the pages carefully and that’s exactly what you’re saying. The $R'$ frame is a train passing by an $R$ frame at rest (a platform) with velocity $v$; the clocks are synchronized in the **moving** frame $R'$ and have proper distance $L$ in $R'$... My mistake!
But looking at the problem this way seems a bit strange to me...
I would have though in a reverse way: clocks being synchronized in a rest frame and someone passing by in a moving frame reading unsynchronized times.

Comment: (2) At the end of the page 191, author gives an example :_Two clocks are synchronised in their rest frame and are held 40 light-minutes apart. If they are viewed from a frame moving along their line
of separation at 0.8 c and the spatially leading clock reads 12:00 pm,
what does the spatially trailing clock read?_
It seems that it matches what I called `reverse way` (or maybe I err?)
Nevertheless, he uses the same formula as before.
All of this puzzles me a bit...

Comment: @Andrew I have already answered all there is to your question as it stands right now. May I suggest that you post your additional questions as separate questions and **include all necessary pages** of your book, as your question is clearly not conceptual (which it seems to be above) but rather about a specific text.

Comment: @Andrew Do also note that the whole point of SR is that all inertial frames are equivalent. In other words, there is no privileged inertial frame that is "at rest". Both frames can equally claim to be "at rest" as there is no absolute rest.

Comment: OK Vincent. Thanks for commenting so long.