Physical meaning of $vx/c^2$ in Lorentz transformation
In Lorentz transformation, this is the formula of time dilation
$$ t' = \gamma \left( t - \frac{vx}{c^2} \right) $$
It can be derivated from the formula of length contraction and be proved mathematically.
But I considered of physical meaning of $vx/c^2$ and didn't comprehend it. $vx/c^2$ is a extra time measured by stationar observer comparing to the time measured by mover.I define $x/c$ as the time light travels between two events, $vx/c$ is the movement of mover during light movement and $vx/c^2$ is the time light travels mover's motion.
We regard $v$ and $c$ to be in a line. When $c$ and $v$ have the same directions , $t$_time measured by stationar observer _ is more than $x/c$, so We subtract $vx/c^2$. But while the light goes $x+xv/c^2$ mover moves more than $vx/c$.
And when $c$ and $v$ have not the same directions, $t$ is less than $x/c$, because the light does not go $x$. So why we add $vx/c^2$ and $t$?
What's the problem here? What does $vx/c^2$ mean?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731491/2451

If the object in the $S$ frame (corresponding to $t$) is not located at $O$, then there would be a corresponding phase difference (or "lack of synchronisation of clocks") between that point and the observer in $O'$ frame. The term represents this phase difference.

You can multiply through by $c$ and get the equivalent relation
$$ ct' = \gamma \left( ct - \beta x \right) $$
where $\beta = v/x$ is the fraction of the speed of light between the frame.  In that format, the first term in parenthesis is the the "uncorrected" distance traveled in time $t$ and the second term in parenthesis is part of the relativistic correction scaled by $\beta$ with $\beta \rightarrow 1$ the limit of relative motion at the speed of light and $\beta \ll 1$ the non-relativistic limit.  The exact form of $\gamma$ and of the $\beta x$ parts of the equation you only get through the derivation.

I believe the rapidity is usually defined differently. The rapidity $\eta$ is related to the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ and the velocity as a fraction of the speed of light $\beta = v/c$ as $\sinh \eta = \gamma \beta$ and $\cosh \eta = \gamma$.

@CompassBearer I edited out the word "rapidity" to avoid confusion / need to get into anything more complex than the level implied by the original question.
